# Swift 3: Can not convert value of type 'int' to expected argument type 'DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, swift3

**Swift 3.0:** Receiving error `Can not convert value of type 'int' to expected argument type 'DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority'` on creating dispatch async queue

```
DispatchQueue.global(priority: 0).async(execute: { () -> Void in

})
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### WARNING, This is deprecated in iOS 8, see below for latest

`DispatchQueue.global` expects the `DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority` enum, which is:

- high
- default
- low
- background

So in your case, you just write:

```
DispatchQueue.global(priority: .background).async(execute: { () -> Void in

})
```

If you want the lowest priority.

A quick check reveals, that `DispatchQueue.global(priority:_)` is deprecated in iOS 8.

#### Latest solution:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            
}
```

Which gives you even more options to choose from:

- background
- utility
- default
- userInitiated
- userInteractive
- unspecified

Comment: I wonder what would be the equivalent of deprecated 'high' in the new options!

Comment: @ioopl Probably `userInteractive` since that is the highest.