# Swift 3 warning for dispatch async

Tags: ios, warnings, swift3, dispatch-async, deprecation-warning

I have this code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default).async {
                let url = URL(string: itemImageURL )
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                if data != nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        cell.advImage!.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }
            }
```

I get this warning in Swift 3:

> 'default' was deprecated in iOS 8.0: Use qos attributes instead

on the first line.

Haven't found yet a solution. Has anybody?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638751/swift-3-can-not-convert-value-of-type-int-to-expected-argument-type-dispatch

Comment: tried it and did not work. the checked answer is what worked fine for me.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

try `qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default` instead of `priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default`

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
            let url = URL(string: itemImageURL )
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            if data != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    cell.advImage!.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since `.default` is the default, you can also just use: `DispatchQueue.global().async { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using **priority** parameter:

```
DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default).async {
 // ...
}
```

use **`qos`** parameter that uses a different enum **`DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default`** but you can also use its enum value as just **`.default`**:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
 // ...
}
```

Swift 3 has brought many changes on GCD(Grand Central Dispatch).

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a property using the Dispatch Framework and updating the UI with some animation within a function it might look something like this.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default)
    // dispatch_after says that it will send this animation every nsec
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.image.setWidth(35)
                self.image.setHeight(35)
            })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is tested for Swift 3.0 on Xcode 8.2.1

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let img2 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[1])

            // Background Thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // Run UI Updates
                self.imageView2.image = img2
            }
        }
```

where **property of QoS** are :

```
background, utility, `default`, userInitiated, userInteractive and unspecified
```

Refer this [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqos) for more details.